# No FIOS Network After Zorin 9 Install on Wireless Desktop PC

Tags: wifi, networking

A friend has a home Verizon FIOS network, connected thusly: Verizon wired/wireless Router > wireless ASUS Windows 7 Desktop PC > wireless HP Windows 8.1 Laptop > wireless HP All-in-One Printer. Note that there are NO hardware devices connected via ethernet cable; all devices have a 'wireless only' connection to the Router, and both Computers have viable internet connections and access to the HP Alli-in-One Printer.

Yesterday, I installed Zorin 9 (stand-alone OS) on their wireless ASUS Desktop PC. The installation was a success and Zorin performs flawlessly; however, they now no longer have internet access! When I click the Network icon, no networks are identified!

How do I restore the wireless internet connection to the ASUS Desktop PC?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a proprietary wifi driver. Check the settings look for "Additional Drivers". You will likely need a wired Internet connection for the driver to download.